# spring kafka consumer is failing to decompress messages [snappy compression]

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, snappy

I am trying to consume messages from kafka using spring-kafka using code below. But I am seeing `java.io.IOException: FAILED_TO_UNCOMPRESS(5)` error from snappy and `org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to decompress record stream`

**Consumer.java**

```
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("batchAckEventProcessor")
  private BatchEventProcessor eventProcessor;
  
  @KafkaListener(
          topics = "MyAckTopic",
          containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
  public void consume(Message<Object> message) {   
      eventProcessor.process(message.getPayload());
  }
}
```

**ConsumerConfig.java**

```
  public ConsumerFactory<String, JSONObject> batchConsumerConfiguration() {
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, env.getProperty("batch_kafka_bootstrap_servers_list"));
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, env.getProperty("batch_consumer_group_id"));
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
        config, new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(JSONObject.class));
  }

  @Bean
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, JSONObject> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, JSONObject> factory =
        new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(batchConsumerConfiguration());
    return factory;
  }
```

**compression type** for topic : snappy

**spring boot version** : 2.1.1.RELEASE

**dependency versions**:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:jar:2.2.15.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.lz4:lz4-java:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.7.1:compile
```

**Error log:**

```
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
18:39:58 20-Dec [ERROR] [o.s.kafka.listener.LoggingErrorHandler  ] [handle              :37  ] [] []-> Error while processing: null 
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to decompress record stream
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Received exception when fetching the next record from MyAckTopic-0. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecordBatch$1.readNext(DefaultRecordBatch.java:268)
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecordBatch$RecordIterator.next(DefaultRecordBatch.java:563)
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1204)
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecordBatch$RecordIterator.next(DefaultRecordBatch.java:532)
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.access$1400(Fetcher.java:1072)
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.nextFetchedRecord(Fetcher.java:1183)
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:562)
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1218)
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:523)
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.access$1400(Fetcher.java:1072)
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1230)
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:562)
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1187)
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:523)
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1154)
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1259)
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:757)
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
    ... 7 common frames omitted
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
Caused by: java.io.IOException: FAILED_TO_UNCOMPRESS(5)
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:708)
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.throw_error(SnappyNative.java:98)
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.rawUncompress(Native Method)
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
    at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.rawUncompress(Snappy.java:474)
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
    at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.uncompress(Snappy.java:513)
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to decompress record stream
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyInputStream.hasNextChunk(SnappyInputStream.java:439)
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecordBatch$1.readNext(DefaultRecordBatch.java:268)
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyInputStream.read(SnappyInputStream.java:466)
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:265)
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.ByteUtils.readVarint(ByteUtils.java:168)
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecord.readFrom(DefaultRecord.java:292)
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecordBatch$1.readNext(DefaultRecordBatch.java:264)
2022-12-20 18:40:01 
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring so I removed those tags and added Snappy - FYI, those Spring versions have been out of support for a very long time now. https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#support

Comment: For debugging, do you get the same error when you try using `kafka-console-consumer`?